# Компиляция java через meson

Tags: java

Работаю под linux. Хочу собрать простую программу на java из двух классов, один использует другой и содержит в себе main. Как это сделать при помощи meson системы сборки? Пытаюсь сделать так, но класс X не виден.

```
myjar1 = jar('testName1', ['src/XTest.java', 'src/X.java'],
        main_class : 'XTest')
```

Однако всё работает если собирать руками так:

```
javac X.java
javac XTest.java
java XTest
```

На сайте meson нашёл пример только с одним файлом

Comment: `, но класс X не виден.` А что конкретно происходит? Ошибка при сборке или выполнении? Приложите сообщения об ошибках и Java-код.

Comment: Подозреваю, что проблема в несоответствии каталогов файловой системы и пакетов Java. Примеры с несколькими файлами есть на Github, можете попробовать сориентироваться: https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/tree/master/test%20cases/java

Comment: ../src/XTest.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
  X x = new X();

Comment: я не указывал в java коде никаких package. т.к. работало без этого

Comment: Попробуйте тогда положить файлы в текущую директорию, а не в `src`. В [документации](https://mesonbuild.com/Java.html) написано, что «... all Java files must be in paths specified by their package, e.g. a class called com.example.Something must be in a Java file situated at com/example/Something.java ».

Answer (score 0):

Помогло избавление от src и перекладывание всего в com папку.